# Jersey not showing response in case it was an error

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I have the following problem...

I'm testing a service that return HTTP responses on GET requests.

My problem is that I would like to view the response even if it was an HTTP 500 / 404 or whatever response.

I would like to view that. But I can't because it throws an exception and that's it.

Is there a way to view a jersey response even if it was an error response?

My code is like this:

```
webResource = client.resource(url);

response = webResource.queryParams(alertParams)
        .header("x-token", token).get(String.class);
```

So when get receives an error response from the service I wont be able to view that although the response is something like this:

{
  "errCode" : "ERR002",
  "errMsg" : "",
  "techErrMsg" : "LoginFailureGeneric"
}

Which is a 400 Bad Request.

Thanks very much for all the help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where you need to spend some time with the docs... [WebRequest#get(Class)](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#get%28java.lang.Class%29) will throw an exception when you get an HTTP error status if you are trying to parse the response as anything other than [ClientResponse](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html).

So all you need to do is change the `.get(String.class)` -> `.get(ClientResponse.class)` and you can pull the entity itself (and the status, and everything else) off of the ClientResponse object sans exceptions.

Comment: Awesome man! Thank you, and a good lesson for me to look at the Docs more!!!!!!! Tanks!

Comment: I'm using Jersey 2.5.1 and this only works in a `JerseyTest` if I call  `get(Response.class)`.